How to get files older than specific date using fluent FTP c#?
I want to delete older files in an FTP directory using FluentFTP. Currently, I can get all the files in the directory using the GetListing method, check their modified dates, and delete the files accordingly.
I'm looking to see if there are better options for searching for files older than x days.

This is not a FluentFTP specific question.
Generally, there is no other way to find files by FTP, unless you list the directories and check the date.

I was wondering if it accepts a filter condition and returns data based on that.
